# How to position controls in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, controls

I am trying to create the UI but I'm having a lot of difficulty just placing controls where I want them to appear on the main screen.  For example I want to add a few ImageButtons but they just seem to snap to one corner and I can't seem to add more than one.

Do I need to use a layout or something?  Can't I just drag and drop and move the controls around where I want?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by reading a few of the developer tools out there. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html This guide will help you get your feet wet with how to properly layout a screen in Android. There are also a bunch of other great guides on there to help with other aspects of the UI. Even though you use C# in Xamarin Studio, the UI portion is native Android so the guides should still be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

try to use **relative layout** , its kind of easy for visual studio developer and others too.
details here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: I don't know if my brain isn't working or something but I don't understand these layout's at all.  From looking at a relative layout, it's talking about things being anchored to the bottom left, bottom right, parent right, center vertical and so on.  Can I not just freely drop controls wherever I want?  If I add a relative layout, add a image button, it automatically snaps to the top left.  I can resize it but I can't move it anywhere.  If I try to add a second ImageButton, the IDE refuses to drop it on the UI.  Sorry, the whole thing is confusing me.

Comment: In eclipse and android studio you are able to drag and drop within a RelativeLayout. TBH I was not impressed with Xamarin when I tried it out, but I had already done a lot of native apps so I was kind of biased.

Comment: which IDE you are using? check the xml code of the layout. check whether relative layout is the Main layout.
To be sure you are using relative layout go to XML code. Delete all the code (in eclipse/adt or android studio) and then back to design then drag and drop relative layout on it. and then use other controls.